# HTML5 <video> resolution

Tags: html, video, browser, resolution

I'm working on a webpage that involves `<video>`s (html5) with strange resolutions (like 720 x 1440).  Are there browser-specific resolution limitations? I can't find any documentation online about this, and I would rather find something official than test it directly, if I can.  Thanks!

Comment: I've not come across anything before.

Comment: I have encountered some limits, especially with devices as opposed to PC/Mac browsers (eg a lot of tablets won't touch anything that exceeds 1080p at 30fps so your sample at 1440 lines won't work) - but it will probably end up as a trial and error process to be sure